# Using Pig to process compressed files which have no extension

Tags: hadoop, compression, apache-pig, gzip

I have a number of files I want to process with pig which have been gzipped. The files do not end with any extension. The documentation that I have seen says that pig determines compression based on file extension, so is there a way to process compressed files without a special file extension. In this case, it is not very feasible to change the file extensions.

Comment: @Mark No although that is an interesting project. I am indeed talking about Apache Pig.

Answer (score 1):

The only possible way is you writing your own loader , and handling this conditions .